# Will immediately add null even if I'm not typing

Tags: java, string, sockets, io

I can't resolve my problem on "server has added null."
It doesn't go to the menu first to process data.

This is also similar to writing client to server question.

Here's my codes:

Student:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Student {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      PrintWriter out = null;
      Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);

      //initialization

      String student = " ";
      String id = " ";
      String name = " ";

      try {
         Socket skt = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
         out = new PrintWriter(skt.getOutputStream(), true);

         while (name.equals("exit")) { //never ending menu
                 System.out.print("Please enter name: ");
                 name = sc.nextLine();
                 System.out.print("Please enter ID Number: ");
                 id = sc.nextLine();
                 student = name +" - "+ id;
                 out.print(student);                 
             }


      } catch(Exception e) {
          System.out.println("Whoops! It didn't work.");

      } finally {
          if (out != null) {
              try {
                  out.close();

      } catch (Exception e) {

              }
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
      ArrayList<String> collector = new ArrayList<String>();
      String x = "";
      try {
         ServerSocket srvr = new ServerSocket(1234);
         Socket skt = srvr.accept();
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(skt.getInputStream()));

         x = in.readLine();
         collector.add(x);
         System.out.println("Server has added "+collector.get(collector.size()-1));


      }
      catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.out.print("Whoops! It didn't work!\n");
      }
   }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the "never ending menu"-condition `select == 2`, your initialization of `int select = 0;` and no other writings to `select` you will *never* execute the code in the loop.

Comment: changed my code to name.equals("quit"); still won't work. and how can i make my server never terminate? i made a boolean isStopped variable but it returns it didn't work

Comment: Which value holds `select` before entering the loop and which value is being tested?

Comment: i actually deleted select. i replaced it with name.equals("exit"); so that if i entered it, it will terminate.

Comment: updated. i didn't update my code immediately because of slow connection.

Comment: And again, which value holds `name` before entering the loop and which value is being tested?

Comment: `name = " ";` outside the loop and `name = sc.nextLine();` inside the loop (never ending menu)

Comment: is this what you mean?

Comment: No, you stay in the loop as long as name equals "exit", and as that is  not even true when entering, your code never enters the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop will never execute as you have set `select = 0`